# Find words contatining & in them

Tags: regex, ms-word

I've been trying to use the find function built into word (eventually through VBA), to find words/abbreveations with and & in them (e.g. m&m, PB&J, B&Q...).

I've tried searching for...

`<[! ]{1,}&[! ]{1,}>`

to try and an & with not a space either side, and the rest of the letters/the whole word, but it doesn't find anything and I don't understand why.

Comment: If there's a digit in the abbreviation should it match?

Comment: `[A-Za-z]+&[a-zA-Z]+` this will

Comment: @PedroLobito Ideally, I can't think of an instance when it should occur, but have no reason to rule it out as a possiblilty.

Comment: I just realised just after posting I could search for <[a-z,A-Z,0-9]{1,}&[a-z,A-Z,0-9]{1,}> instead, which works. But I would still like to know why the first one doesn't work.

Comment: @CodeManiac I just tried it and it doesn't work, but I have a feeling that's probably to do with ms-word regexs being different to others

Comment: Have yuo tried `<[! ]@&[! ]@>`? It seems this pattern finds matches. Note that `@` is a quantifier matching 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *wildcard* Find with:

```
Find = <[! ]@&[! ]@>
```

works for me, as does:

```
Find = <[! ]@&*>
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works on a new document but for some reason gets stuck on something on the first page of my exisiting document (assuming a bug). Any idea why `{1,}` doesn't worj but `@` does? As I was under the impression they did the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure why {1,} doesn't work in this case. Note the simplified Find expression I've added to my Answer. Be aware, though, that expression won't work as expected if you have strings ending in & (e.g. B&).